# How to run a `polkadot-dev` or `kusama-dev` node?

Tags: polkadot, kusama, chainspec, polkadot-sdk

Since the removal of the `polkadot` and `kusama` runtimes from the `polkadot-sdk`, running one of those chains with `-dev` or `-local` runs a `rococo` node.
How can I get a `polkdadot-dev\-local` or `kusama-dev\local` if I need to, e.g. to retrieve the metadata?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-dev` and `-local` chains are not available in the `polkadot-sdk` nodes since their corresponding `chain-spec` has been removed and is now present in the `fellowship` repo along with the other runtimes. So the question is, how to generate the missing `chain-specs`?

Well, the `fellowship` repo has a tool called `chain-spec-generator`, to which you have to pass the name of the `chain-spec` you need and you can retrieve it as a raw `chain-spec` or as a regular `.json` `chain-spec`. Once you have the `chain-spec` you need, you just need to specify it with the `--chain` flag when running the node.

E.g:

Clone the [polkadot-fellows/runtimes](https://github.com/polkadot-fellows/runtimes/tree/main) repository and from the ROOT run:

```bash
$ unset SKIP_WASM_BUILD
$ cargo build --release -p chain-spec-generator --features fast-runtime
$ ./target/release/chain-spec-generator polkadot-dev > polkadotDevChainSpec.json
```

Clone the [polkadot-sdk](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk) repository, checkout the most recent releases tag and from the ROOT run:

```bash
$ cargo build --release --bin polkadot-prepare-worker --features fast-runtime
$ cargo build --release --bin polkadot-execute-worker --features fast-runtime
$ cargo build --release --bin polkadot --features fast-runtime
$ cp ../runtimes/polkadotDevChainSpec.json .
$ ./target/release/polkadot --chain polkadotDevChainSpec.json
```

For this example we want a plain `chain-spec` for a `polkadot-dev` node with a reduced epoch duration (therefore the `--features fast-runtime`). If we wanted the `raw` `chain-spec`, let's say to run with a `zombienet`, we would need to pass the `--raw` flag to the `chain-spec-generator`.

*NOTE: The `chain-spec-builder` is only present in the `main` branch of the `runtimes` repo.*

Comment: This is incredibly helpful! Thanks